# How to find large partition in cassandra except system.log?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

How can we find large partitions on our cassandra cluster before came into system.log? we are facing some performance issue due to this. Can anyone help me. We have cassandra version 2.0.11 and 2.1.16.

Answer (score 4):

You can look into output of the `nodetool tablestats` (or `nodetool cfstats` in the older versions of Cassandra) - for every table it has line **Compacted partition maximum bytes** together with other information, like in this example when max partition size is about 268Mb:

```
    Table: table_name
    SSTable count: 2
    Space used (live): 147638509
    Space used (total): 147638509
    .....
    Compacted partition minimum bytes: 43
    Compacted partition maximum bytes: 268650950
    Compacted partition mean bytes: 430941
    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 8256.0
    Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 10239
    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
    Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
    .....
```

But `nodetool tablestats` gives you an information for current node only, so you'll need to execute it on every node of the cluster.

**Update**: You can find largest partitions using different tools:

- https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools has [describe](https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools#describe) command that shows largest/widest partitions. This command [will be also available in Cassandra 4.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11483).
- for DataStax products the DSBulk tool [supports counting of partitions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/countOptions.html).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but require keys of those partitions? any command to find if any

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have seen but seems available for 3.x but as I have mentioned that we have 2.x. Also, we require keys of wide or large partitions so that we can handle before coming into compaction.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `nodetool tablehistograms -- <keyspace> <table>` command provides statistics about a table, including read/write latency, partition size, column count, and number of SSTables.

Below is the example output:

```
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                  
50%             0.00             73.46              0.00         223875792             61214
75%             0.00             88.15              0.00         668489532            182785
95%             0.00            152.32              0.00        1996099046            654949
98%             0.00            785.94              0.00        3449259151           1358102
99%             0.00            943.13              0.00        3449259151           1358102
Min             0.00             24.60              0.00              5723                 4
Max             0.00           5839.59              0.00        5960319812           1955666
```

This provides proper stats of the table like 95% percentile of raw_data table has partition size of 107MB and max of 3.44GB.

Hope this helps to figure out performance issue.

Comment: Thanks but we require to key of particular partitions so that we can delete large partitions based on keys.

Comment: Have you found the way to do this? I am also trying to figure out the key that has the largest partition.